# accessing passed value from server to client outside Runnable thread class

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, swing, client-server

i'm writing a client-server desktop application in Java. i wrote a server that runs (opens socket) & waits for the clients to connect. clients doesn't communicate with database (MySQL) directly, they send query to server, server executes query & converts the result set to JSON & sends it back to client.
on client side i wrote a Listener class:

```
private class Listner implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private final Socket socket;
    private BufferedReader input;

    Listner(Socket s) {
       socket = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String message;
                message = input.readLine();
                sharedInputFromServer = input.readLine();
                System.out.println("message value in run(): " + message);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(30);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientDashboard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public void start () {
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("input value in start() :" + input);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       if (t == null) {
          t = new Thread (this, "client");
          t.start ();
        }
    }
}
```

for using the returned data in client GUI, i defined a variable

```
public String sharedInputFromServer;
```

and for testing i set ActionPerformed for a button to update a label with returned value

```
private void btn_sendToServerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    if (null != output) {
        String textToSend = "SELECT unit_id, unit_name FROM units;";
        output.println(textToSend);
        System.out.println("got the share: " + sharedInputFromServer);
        lbl_clientStatus.setText(sharedInputFromServer);
    }
```

when i click on button for the first time sharedInputFromServer returns null, for the second time it returns null again (message in run() takes value) & when i click on button for the third time it returns the desired value.

1. why it doesn't work at first?
2. is this the right & proper way to receive query result from server & use it on client?

Comment: Other issues: I would avoid putting the Thread object **within** the Runnable. Let the calling code be the code that starts and controls the thread object itself.

Comment: Please see edits

Comment: ..........hello?

Answer (score 1):

> why it doesn't work at first?

You're sending a query via client to server, that then extracts data from a database, and then sends it back to the client. This is never going to happen instantaneously, and you shouldn't *expect* it to happen instantaneously. You need to re-wire and re-think how you get information from the server.

> is this the right & proper way to receive query result from server & use it on client?

There's no single one *right* way, but there are some general rules that should be followed. Understand that the server will reply to your query asynchronously -- that is, it won't occur immediately, you won't know exactly *when* it will occur, and it will occur on a different Thread. So your solution needs to be asynchronous as well.

Since this appears to be a Swing GUI, if this were my application, I wouldn't have a line such as:

```
lbl_clientStatus.setText(sharedInputFromServer);
```

in the same code used to send a query to the server, since this code assumes immediate response, and might be code that you'd use in a linear console program, but not what you should use in an event-driven GUI that has to wait for the server to respond. Instead, again assuming that this is Swing, I'd put my listener code within a `SwingWorker<Void, String>`, and I'd use the worker's publish/process method pair to allow the data to update the client GUI asynchronously and when it is available. Another option is to use a `SwingWorker<Void, Void>` and to listen for changes by adding a PropertyChangeListener to the worker, and listening to a mutually agreed upon property.  The advantages to these approaches is that for both, the client GUI would be notified by the worker when its state has changed, and could respond accordingly, and also all Swing GUI changes would be made on the Swing event thread, avoiding messy concurrency exceptions.  Please check out this tutorial for the details:

[Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

---

For example, say your client GUI were called SimpleClientGui, and say that it had a JTextArea called outputTextArea, and a public method that allows outside classes the ability to append text to the text area:

```
public class SimpleClientGui extends JPanel {

    // ...
    private JTextArea outputTextArea = new JTextArea(25, 50);

    // ...

    public void appendToOutput(String text) {
        outputTextArea.append(text);
    }
```

You could create a SwingWorker, say called  ServerListener, that called the above appendToOutput method **on the Swing event thread**, like so:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class ServerListener extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {
    private SimpleClientGui simpleClient;
    private Scanner scanner;

    public ServerListener(SimpleClientGui simpleClient, InputStream inputStream) {
        this.simpleClient = simpleClient;
        this.scanner = new Scanner(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            // push the next line to the process method
            publish(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        if (scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String chunk : chunks) {
            // this is called on the Swing event thread
            simpleClient.appendToOutput(chunk + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```